# How to aggregate values into an array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a two tables

```
Student
--------
Id  Name
1   John    
2   David
3   Will

Grade
---------
Student_id  Mark
1           A
2           B
2           B+
3           C
3           A
```

Is it possible to make native Postgresql SELECT to get results like below:

```
Name    Array of marks
-----------------------
'John',     {'A'}
'David',    {'B','B+'}
'Will',     {'C','A'}
```

But **not** like below

```
Name    Mark
----------------
'John',     'A'
'David',    'B'
'David',    'B+'
'Will',     'C'
'Will',     'A'
```

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Use array_agg: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/5099e/1

```
SELECT s.name,  array_agg(g.Mark) as marks        
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN Grade g ON g.Student_id = s.Id
GROUP BY s.Id
```

By the way, if you are using Postgres 9.1, you [don't need to repeat](http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/08/postgresql-recognizing-functional.html) the columns on SELECT to GROUP BY, e.g. you don't need to repeat the student name on GROUP BY. You can merely GROUP BY on primary key. If you remove the primary key on student, you need to repeat the student name on GROUP BY.

```
CREATE TABLE grade
    (Student_id int, Mark varchar(2));

INSERT INTO grade
    (Student_id, Mark)
VALUES
    (1, 'A'),
    (2, 'B'),
    (2, 'B+'),
    (3, 'C'),
    (3, 'A');


CREATE TABLE student
    (Id int primary key, Name varchar(5));

INSERT INTO student
    (Id, Name)
VALUES
    (1, 'John'),
    (2, 'David'),
    (3, 'Will');
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much about your remark about select/group, that is so awesome! That was really annoying!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836831/postgres-aggregate-column-into-array

Answer (score 12):

What I understand you can do something like this:

```
SELECT p.p_name, 
    STRING_AGG(Grade.Mark, ',' ORDER BY Grade.Mark) As marks
FROM Student
LEFT JOIN Grade ON Grade.Student_id = Student.Id
GROUP BY Student.Name;
```

**EDIT**

I am not sure. But maybe something like this then:

```
SELECT p.p_name, 
    array_to_string(ARRAY_AGG(Grade.Mark),';') As marks
FROM Student
LEFT JOIN Grade ON Grade.Student_id = Student.Id
GROUP BY Student.Name;
```

Reference [here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/191-String-Aggregation-in-PostgreSQL,-SQL-Server,-and-MySQL.html)

Comment: I think he wants a pgsql array, not a comma-separated string

Answer (score 11):

[Michael Buen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10928679) got it right. I got what I needed using array_agg.

Here just a basic query example in case it helps someone:

```
SELECT directory, ARRAY_AGG(file_name) 
FROM table 
WHERE type = 'ZIP' 
GROUP BY directory;
```

And the result was something like:

```
|     parent_directory    |                 array_agg              |  
+-------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| /home/postgresql/files  | {zip_1.zip,zip_2.zip,zip_3.zip}        |
| /home/postgresql/files2 | {file1.zip,file2.zip}                  |
```

---

This post also helped me a lot: ["Group By" in SQL and Python Pandas](https://mode.com/blog/group-by-sql-python).
It basically says that it is more efficient to use only PSQL when possible, but that Python Pandas can be useful to achieve extra functionalities in the filtering process.

Answer (score 9):

You could use the following:

```
SELECT Student.Name as Name,
       (SELECT array(SELECT Mark FROM Grade WHERE Grade.Student_id = Student.Id))
       AS ArrayOfMarks 
FROM Student
```

As described here: http://www.mkyong.com/database/convert-subquery-result-to-array/

Comment: Thanks a lot, `array` function is much faster than `array_agg`, especially, when there are millions of records.