# Postgres: aggregate column into array

Tags: postgresql

I have the following two tables:

```
# select * from list;
  list_id |         name
 ---------+----------------------
        9 | Popular
       11 | Recommended
```

and

```
# select * from list_item;
 list_id | game_id | position 
---------+---------+----------
      11 |       2 |        0
       9 |      10 |        1
      11 |       5 |        1
      11 |       4 |        4
      11 |       6 |        2
      11 |       7 |        3
       9 |       3 |        0
```

I want an array of game IDs per list like so:

```
 list_id |     name    | game_ids
---------+-------------+------------
       9 | Popular     | {3,10}
      11 | Recommended | {2,5,6,7,4}
```

I came up with the following solution but it seems rather complicated especially the bit where I get the completed array using `distinct on` and  `last_value`:

```sql
with w as (
  select
    list_id,
    name,
    array_agg(game_id) over (partition by list_id order by position)
  from list
  join list_item
  using (list_id)
)
select
  distinct on (list_id)
  list_id,
  name,
  last_value(array_agg) over (partition by list_id)
from w
```

Any suggestions how to simplify this?

Comment: Is it a requirement to use a window function?

Comment: If your problem in `order by` then you can specify it in the aggregate for some aggregate functions, so: `select list_id, name, array_agg(game_id order by position) from list join list_item using (list_id) group by list_id, name;` should be enough.

Comment: @AlexanderGuz No, it is not a requirement to use window. Sorry, should have made this clearer.

Comment: @Abelisto Thank you, this is indeed much simpler.

Comment: Post that as an answer, and eventually accept it, so it the question does not stay answered.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a better solution as suggested by Abelisto in the comments:

```
select
  list_id,
  name,
  array_agg(game_id order by position)
from list
join list_item
using (list_id)
group by list_id, name
```