# equivalent of pandas groupby('v1').apply(lambda x:['v2'].nunique()) in postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pandas

What is the equivalent of pandas `df.groupby('v1').apply(lambda x:['v2'].nunique())` with posgres sql?

i.e. given a table I want to know the number of unique values of `v2` for each `v1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you mean

```
SELECT v1, count(DISTINCT v2)
FROM df
GROUP BY v1;
```

Comment: can potentially be sorted as well?

Comment: Yes, just add an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT v1, COUNT(v2) FROM t GROUP BY v1;`

OR

`SELECT v1, COUNT(DISTINCT v2) FROM t GROUP BY v1;`

Answer (score 0):

Also check his post [array_agg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928210/postgresql-aggregate-array).
It was helpful to me. It will give you an array list. I just did something like:

`SELECT directory, ARRAY_AGG(file_name) 
FROM table 
WHERE type = 'ZIP' 
GROUP BY directory;`

And the result was something like:

`parent_directory  |                 array_agg              |   ------------------------+----------------------------------------+
/home/postgresql/files  | {zip_1.zip,zip_2.zip,zip_3.zip}        |
/home/postgresql/files2 | {file1.zip,file2.zip}                  |`

---

This post also helped me a lot: ["Group By" in SQL and Python Pandas](https://mode.com/blog/group-by-sql-python).
It basically says that it is more convenient to use only SQL when possible, but that Python Pandas can be useful to achieve extra functionalities in the filtering process.

I hope it helps