# Return distinct/unique records of join table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have joined multiple tables to structure my record like below, but now I want to return unique standards that are not assigned to `term_year_id 301` (i.e. I want to return `standard_id 1 and 4`).

```
id   standard_id   term_id     term_year_id
 1        1          200            300
 2        2          200            300
 3        2          201            301
 4        3          202            300
```

I tried to return records that are not equal to `term_year_id 301` but that would return `standard 2` which I don't want. I also tried group/having but my syntax is wrong?

```
def school_standards
  @standards = @school.achievement_standards
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN term_standards ON achievement_standards.id = term_standards.achievement_standard_id")
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN terms ON terms.id = term_standards.term_id")
  .group("terms.term_year_id")
  .having("terms.term_year_id <> 301)

end
```

What's the right way to do this? I'm using rails with postgres.

Comment: Oh!  You want to return all the standard_ids that do not also include a term_year_id of 301.  You might  have to tell us  which database you're using.

Comment: But I don't want to return `standard_id 2` because it's in `term_year_id 300 and 301`

Comment: I'm using postgres with rails

Comment: Then I think what you are going to do is a group().having() where your group by goes into an array and your having is NOT including 301.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928210/postgresql-aggregate-array
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html

Comment: What is the syntax to group a joined table? I'm getting errors like `column must appear in GROUP BY clause`. Note: I added my code to the question

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you could get a unique list of standard_id for which term_year_id equals 301 and then just kick them out.  something like the below should work:

```
select a.*
from myTable a
where standard_id not in (select distinct standard_id from myTable where term_year_id = 301)
```

Comment: Would you be able to share how to do this in rails?

Answer (score 0):

Given the table above, and the model for the table 'Stt' (Standard Term Term_year)

```
  def test_the_ticket
    rows = [
      {standard_id: 1, term_id: 200, term_year_id: 300},
      {standard_id: 2, term_id: 200, term_year_id: 300},
      {standard_id: 2, term_id: 201, term_year_id: 301},
      {standard_id: 3, term_id: 202, term_year_id: 300}
    ]
    Stt.create! rows
    results = Stt.select(:standard_id, 'array_agg(term_year_id) as term_year_ids').group('standard_id').having('NOT array_agg(term_year_id) @> Array[301]')
    assert_equal([1,3], results.map(&:standard_id))
  end
```

There may be a better/prettier way, but this'll do.

```
  Stt Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "stts"."standard_id", array_agg(term_year_id) as term_year_ids FROM "stts" GROUP BY "stts"."standard_id" HAVING (NOT array_agg(term_year_id) @> Array[301])
```